# Maximum modulus of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider an entire function $f(z)$ with the condition of $| f''(z)| \leq 2$ ($f''$ is the second derivative of f). If $f(0)=3$ and $f(i)=4+2i$, what is the maximum of $|f(z)|$ interior of $C: |z|=1?$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and *include your work and thoughts on the problem.* These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For a starter: $f''$ is an entire function and bounded. Does that tell you something?